# HTML Img Src Variable

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am trying to pass an array of image urls (in String format) from a python application to an HTML web page. In this HTML web page, I run a Jinja for loop in which I try to display a series of images whose sources are in the array I passed to the HTML webpage. However, the images are not appearing. Below is my code for this attempt. imgLinks is the array that contains all the urls of my image sources, and the variable length represents the length of this array.

```
{% for arrayPos in range(length) %}

  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <img src=imgLinks[arrayPos] width=30% height=20%> </img>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

{% endfor %}
```

Per the request of someone, here is my python code. I am basically calling from an API to get my information.

```
@app.route('/explorelaunches')
def explorelaunches():
    response = requests.get("https://ll.thespacedevs.com/2.0.0/launch/upcoming/")
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    launches = jsonResponse["results"]

    names = []
    startTimes = []
    padNames = []
    descriptions = []
    imgLinks = []

    for launch in launches:

        if (launch['name'] is None):
            names.append("N/A")
        else:
            names.append(launch['name'])

        if (launch['net'] is None):
            startTimes.append("N/A")
        else:
            dateString = launch['net']
            finalDate = parse(dateString).strftime('%B %d, %Y')
            startTimes.append(finalDate)

        if (launch['pad'] is None or launch['pad']['name'] is None):
            padNames.append("N/A")
        else:
            padNames.append(launch['pad']['name'])

        if (launch['mission'] is None or launch['mission']['description'] is None):
            descriptions.append("N/A")
        else:
            descriptions.append(launch['mission']['description'])

        if (launch['image'] is None):
            imgLinks.append("N/A")
        else:
            imgLinks.append(launch['image'])

    return render_template("explorelaunches.html", username=session.get(names=names, startTimes=startTimes, padNames=padNames, descriptions=descriptions, length=len(names), imgLinks=imgLinks)
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `length`? What is `imgLinks`? Why can't you simply use `for img in imgLinks`? Please post the Python code associated as well.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an list of URLs, you can directly iterate over the list in jinja template. I have just made bit of correction according to the information you have provide.

```
{% for image_link in imgLinks%}

  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <img src={{ image_link }} width=30% height=20%> </img> <!--you forgot to put url inside {{...}}-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

{% endfor %}
```